# toggleClass but only one div clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm pulling in dynamic data from an outsource that is generating code to my site, so I'm trying to add functionality on top of what is being pulled in. I have a jquery toggleClass setup where I click a div and it toggles the class 'active' to display a job description and then hide the content on second click. the problem is when I click one they all open since they have the same class name. How can I target just the one I click and leave the others closed?

hiding children on click but not liking that for aesthetics

```
   $('.resumator-job').click(function() {
    $('.resumator-job-description').toggleClass('active');
});
```

only div clicked opens, others stay closed until they are clicked individually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `this` to target the specific element in jQuery. `this` refers to the element at hand.

You can play about with this! Try adding `console.log($(this));` to your function and see which element it lists.

[W3Schools has a demo](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_sel_this) of using `this`.

```
$('.resumator-job').click(function() {
    $('.resumator-job-description', this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

> `$(this)` - Selects the current HTML element - [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `.find()` here as well to get what you are after.

```
$('.resumator-job').click(function() {
    $(this).find('.resumator-job-description').toggleClass('active');
});
```

Demo:

```js
$('.resumator-job').click(function() {
    $(this).find('.resumator-job-description').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.resumator-job {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.resumator-job-description {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

.active {
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='resumator-job'>
  <div class='resumator-job-description'>more stuff</div>
</div>
<div class='resumator-job'>
  <div class='resumator-job-description'>more stuff</div>
</div>
<div class='resumator-job'>
  <div class='resumator-job-description'>more stuff</div>
</div>
<div class='resumator-job'>
  <div class='resumator-job-description'>more stuff</div>
</div>
```